# Using @AfterThrowing with @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-aop

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class ExceptionAlerts {
    public ExceptionAlerts() {
        System.err.println("Class Scanned");
    }

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "com.name.papp.star", throwing = "ex")
public void doRecoveryAction(Throwable ex) throws Throwable {
    System.err.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Recovery Actions++++++++++++++++");
    }
}
```

Service Interface

```
public interface SignInService {
    CustomerSignInDTO signIn()
        throws LappException;
}
```

Service Implementation Class

```
public class SignInServiceImpl implements SignInService {
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public CustomerSignInDTO signInCustomer(CustomerDeviceDTO customerDeviceDTO, 
                         String mobileNumber, boolean createIfNotExist) 
                         throws LappException {
                  // Throwing Exception Here
    }
}
```

Problem -
Spring-Boot-1.2.5

The method `doRecoveryActions` never gets called. I am also using `@ExceptionHandler` somewhere to prepare the error response. Is it because `@ExceptionHandler` catches all the exceptions and `doRecoveryActions` is never called? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it work if you change signature to doRecoveryAction(Throwable  ex)?

Comment: No it doesn't. Tried that as well.

Comment: Pls, post the real pointcut & executed method signature. @ExceptionHandler doesn't spoil AOP handlers

Comment: Trouble is with your pointcut expression. Try  pointcut = "execution(* com.name.papp.star.*)" to scan full package or   "execution(* com.name.papp.star.auth.service.impl.signInCustomer(..))" for exact method

Comment: Around("execution(* com..*ServiceImpl.*(..))") works perfectly with Around , but gives error when I use AfterThrowing. Could you please suggest an alternate, I have to give package based restrictions.

Comment: Please share the exception / error encountered while using pointcut `execution(* com..*ServiceImpl.*(..))`

Comment: Neither `com.name.papp.star` nor `execution(* com.name.papp.star.*)` are valid pointcuts, but `execution(* com..*ServiceImpl.*(..))` is indeed valid. If it does not work with `AfterThrowing`, please show your exception call stack. Besides, I hope you know that an after-throwing advice can never catch the exception that has been thrown, only react on it by e.g. logging something or cleaning up a resource or whatever. If you want to catch the exception and then handle it, you need to use try-catch inside an around advice.